# Gradle module package not found error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I've 3 modules in my project:

**Lib** - `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
**Proj A** - `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
**Proj B** - `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Both project inport the lib in their **build.gradle** file:
     `compile project(path: ':lib-module')`

The **settings.gradle** imports it to:
 `include ':projectA-module', ':projectB-module', ':lib-module'`

The gradle builds correctly, and I can import my lib classes inside my projects and navigate through the code. The only problem appears in compile time where I get this kind of errors showing that the lib classes and packages cannot be found:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':projectA-module:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   .../Class.java
>   Error:(27, 42) Gradle: error: package com.mylib.somepackage does not exist

What's happening?